# thread too slow on sockets

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing a server for mobile machines that implements a socket server to receive their connection, by using Visual Studio Express 2013.

It uses `Net.Sockets.TcpListener.AcceptSocket` to assign the connection to a `Net.Sockets.Socket`.
It start a new `Threading.Thread` for each new socket created, with a while cycle to receive, parsing and write data to the socket.
It uses the property `x.Available` to get the data count and reads that data with the `x.Receive(buffer, datalen, Net.Sockets.SocketFlags.None)`.
It parses the data received and create the answer.
Finally it uses the  `x.Send(answerbuffer, answerdatalen, Net.Sockets.SocketFlags.None)` to transmit the answer.

The code works correcty on receive and send the answer, but it is quite slow.

I put some check on the code to get the elapsed time on each operation of the code and I get that average values:
- socket read and copy data from buffer to a list (of bytes): 100-200 ms
- data parsing and creating of an answer buffer list (of bytes): 150-300 ms
- converting buffer list (of bytes) to buffer array of bytes and socket send: 70-200 ms

Keeping in mind data receive for packet is about 150 byte length and data transmit is about 100 byte length, the timings for each execution part of the thread are quite high. So when the server receives more connections toghether, the answers slows down or stops for a while.

Does this method of using a Socket and a Thread for each connection on the server is bad?
Do I make a search of some other class to manage the data streaming or thread parallel executions?
Does visual studio express have some limitation on working with threads?

Thank you for the help.
Matteo

Comment: If these are transient connections it's probably going to be significantly faster to use AcceptSocketAsync since that will use a thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this method of using a Socket and a Thread for each connection on the server is bad?

Yes, very bad. Threads don't scale at all, and additionally: if you're using threads per socket, an accidental or malicious DDOS is virtually guaranteed.

You can *just about* get away with thread-per-socket at the client, if you're only connecting to a few sockets. At the server: that's just death.

Server socket IO is almost always done using async IO. This gets complicated *really quickly*, especially when talking about back-buffers etc, but : there's an entire new API available in modern .NET for this scenario: "pipelines" - that deals with all of the the threading, memory pooling, and back-buffer management *for you*. It *really* isn't going to work on Visual Studio 2013, though, so... update if possible? If that is of interest, I have a [multi-part saga on using pipelines](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html).

If that isn't possible, a good place to start might be something like `SocketAsyncEventArgs`, but again: this is a *really really deep rabbit hole*, and frankly it is mostly a solved problem. If you *can* switch to a pre-rolled implementation, I'd recommend it.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

I updated Visual Studio to 2019 and I studied your saga on pipelines.
I think to be ready about the use of pipelines for memory management, but I have many difficulties on decide thread management.

I have a maximum number of 50 machines that can connect at the same time and each of them can stay connected and transmit data updates randomly for hours.
The server ask for machine heartbeat (connection is still alive?) every 5 minutes and routes data between connections.

Do you please have some hint also about "async IO" management for this specific use?

Comment: @matteo with pipelines? there's literally nothing to do; you'll get activated automatically